# Quoted encoded text got by client sending mail from php

Tags: php, email

I have a small php app which sends email answer to the users filling a form. Some clients (but not all) claim, that a Quoted Printable encoded email got.
I use php *mail* function, the subject and the body of mail contain ISO-8859-2 coded text.
When I define Content type:

> header .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-2\r\n"

All clients got Quoted printable encoded a-mail.
Tips, ideas?

Comment: `text/plain` is your issue.

Comment: @Lawrence should I use "Content-Type: text/plain" without charset? Thanks.

Comment: No, the issue is that header sends it as plain text, so if you got break tags or any HTML then it will show as `</br>` etc. I suggest you look into using [PHPmailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) instead if you're looking to send HTML based emails.

Comment: @Lawrence no the html tags are problem (plain text mails are sent) but for example =E9 instead of e' (e  acute), that is called Quoted printable coding.

Comment: It should be `Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: @Lawrence,as I metioned the mail body has ISO-8859-2 charset.